# How to transform QImage from C++ to Android?

Tags: android, c++

Currently I am developing an Android app. I have to convert an algorithm from C++ to Android. Most of the code was converted but I don't know what symbolize the next lines in C++.

```
 QImage my_image(W,H, QImage::Format_RGB32);
 my_image.fill(Qt:black);
```

In my code my_image was declared a Bitmap. 
Please help me with the equivalent code for Android or please specify what does the described C++ code.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

The code

```
 QImage my_image(W,H, QImage::Format_RGB32);
 my_image.fill(Qt:black);
```

is a QT GUI framework code that creates RGB32 image with width W and height H and fills it with a black color.

RGB32 image pixels consist of bytes arranged in memory like this:

[ B G R A ] [ B G R A ] [ B G R A ] [ B G R A ] ...

B - blue pixel component
G - green pixel component
R - red pixel component
A - padding byte (is used as alpha pixel component in related formats ARGB32 and ARGB32-premultiplied)